# Extjs 4.2 float a button to a fixed location in the application

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJs 4.2

My app needs to a have a button that will invoke a panel, that holds the navigation tree show once clicked.

This button needs to be visible at all times, and centered vertical to the middle and to the right of the screen.

How do I achieve this behavior? I don't want to nest the button in a panel, it should be a part of the view port...

Here is what I have tried:

```
Ext.define('NG.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    id: 'appviewport',
    items: [{
        itemId: 'app-header',
        xtype: 'appheader',
        region: 'north',
        weight: 10,
        border: false,
        height: 60
    }, {
        itemId: 'navigation',
        xtype: 'button',
        region: 'west',
        weight:15
    }, {
        xtype: 'carddeckmanager',
        region: 'center',
        weight:10,
        border: false,
        cls:'n-cardmanager-box',
        items: [{
            itemId: 'dashboard',
            xtype: 'dashboard'
        }]
    }]
});
```

but this makes the button expand as the height of the viewport.

Comment: you have tried please update jsfiddle?

Comment: Understood your requirement, but we can't able to provide code for your requirement. Make an try and come up with the code, if you face any problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to *float* that button, there's no sense in adding it to a container or the viewport. Render it to the document body, configure it with `floating: true`, and give it a z-index that will ensure that it remains above any window (if that's what you want).

Then you can position it where you want with its `alignTo` method but, better yet, use `anchorTo` so that it sticks where you put it, even when the browser is resized.

All of this gives us:

```
var body = Ext.getBody();

// Create the button
var button = Ext.widget('button', {
    text: "Yo"
    ,floating: true
    ,renderTo: body
});

// z-index
// Ext4's windows default z-index starts from 29000
button.setZIndex(40000);

// Anchor the right of the button to the right of the document body
// with a 5px horizontal offset.
button.anchorTo(body, 'r-r', [-5, 0]);
```

Put this code somewhere in the startup process of your application. Candidates could be the `init` method of your application, the `initComponent` method of your viewport, or a single `afterrender` listener on the viewport...

Now, if what you want is just that the button remains visible in the right border of the viewport but without it filling the whole region, you need to wrap it in a container with an appropriate layout. For example, add this to your viewport:

```
{    
    region: 'west',
    layout: {type: 'hbox', pack: 'center', align: 'middle'},
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "Viewport button"
    }]
}
```

Comment: how can I stop the panel from being dragged while I'm scrolling the page , I tried setting the floating to false and it didn't work? I don't need the Panel to move when I'm scrolling once I aligned it. Thank you

Comment: Err... I can only guess what you're trying to do... Have you tried `alignTo` instead of `anchorTo`?

Comment: This works great. Just one minor change, Instead of `button.anchorTo(body, 'r-r', [-5, 0]);` make it `button.getEl().anchorTo(body, 'r-r', [-5, 0]);`

Observer getEl() after button.